# SwiftUI: Check if Angle ranges overlap

Tags: swift, swiftui, angle

I am trying to implement following function:

```swift
func areRangesOverlapping(min1: Angle, max1: Angle, min2: Angle, max2: Angle) -> Bool
```

Where one can imaging the ranges being on a circle and always going clockwise from min to max. So e.g. min1 could be 340 degrees and max1 could be 20 degrees (then the range would be 40 degrees long).

The following solution doesn't work since min1 <= max1 is not always true:

```swift
func areRangesOverlapping(min1: Angle, max1: Angle, min2: Angle, max2: Angle) -> Bool {
     let range1 = min1...max1
     let range2 = min2...max2

     return range1.overlaps(range2)
}
```

Comment: I gave you a prompt, you can define a condition which can work in 2 way: first you can add min to max like: 380 or you can make 340 to -20, since you are returning Boolen it could be enough

Answer (score 0):

```swift
func areRangesOverlapping(min1: Angle, max1: Angle, min2: Angle, max2: Angle) -> Bool {
    let min1 = min1.asDoubleBetween0and360
    let max1 = max1.asDoubleBetween0and360
    let min2 = min2.asDoubleBetween0and360
    let max2 = max2.asDoubleBetween0and360

    let isRange1OverZero = min1 > max1
    let isRange2OverZero = min2 > max2

    if !isRange1OverZero && !isRange2OverZero {
        let range1 = min1...max1
        let range2 = min2...max2
        return range1.overlaps(range2)
    } else if isRange1OverZero && !isRange2OverZero {
        return max2 > min1 || max1 > min2
    } else if isRange2OverZero && !isRange1OverZero {
        return max1 > min2 || max2 > min1
    } else {
        let range1 = min1...(max1 + 360)
        let range2 = min2...(max2 + 360)
        return range1.overlaps(range2)
    }
}

extension Angle {
    var asDoubleBetween0and360: Double {
        var result = fmod(self.degrees, 360)
        if result < 0 {
            result += 360.0
        }
        return result
    }
}
```